# y-axes misaligning in highcharts after zooming in

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

In my application, I create a highcharts object, with zoomtype set to xy. Each dataset has its own y-axis due to different range of values (e.g. one dataset could have an infinite max, whereas other percentage based values are limited to 100/-100). If a dataset with only positive values and a dataset with both positive and negative values are loaded, I can align the zeros of the y-axes nicely.

However, upon zooming in, the zeros disalign. If I would zoom in on the range of 20 to -10, datasets that don't have any negative values will only show the range of 20 to 0. After resetting the zoom everything is fine. If I use the y-axis that's added by default by highcharts, the bars of the column graph are aligned nicely upon zooming in. However, this doesn't solve the issue of the zeros disaligning. I've been running into this issue for a few days now and I can't seem to solve it. I've tried playing around with the yAxis settings, and other settings of the graph, but this didn't solve anything for me either.

Any help would be appreciated and if needed I can supply some of my code.

Code for adding y-axis:

```
function addYAxis(opposite){
chart.addAxis({

    // set ID to axis number
    id: yAxisCounter,

    // Don't align the labels on the y-axis
    alignTicks: false,

    // Don't allow decimals values on the axis labels
    allowDecimals: false,

    // set max padding to 0
    maxPadding: 0,

    // set minimum padding to 0 so the chart does not add any padding
    minPadding: 0,

    // Hide this axis if it doesn't have associated values and/or labels
    showEmpty: false,

    // Set the space between labels on the axis
    //tickInterval: tickInterval,
    tickPixelInterval: 25,

    // set the color of the gridlines in the chart
    gridLineColor: '#FFFFFF',

    // set the location of the yAxis
    opposite: opposite,

    // Construct label value that is shown when hovering over a bar in the chart
    labels: {
            formatter: function(){
                return this.value;
            },
            style: {

                // Set the color of the label text
                color: getColor(),

                // Set the letter size of the label text
                fontSize: 10
            }
    }
});
}

function addSeries(id, vals){
// Add a series of data to the chart;
chart.addSeries({

  // Construct series name
  name: id,

  // Construct identifier to we can distinguish different datasets
  identifier: id,

  // Set the data
  data: vals,

  // Link these series to the current y-Axis
  yAxis: yAxisCounter,

  // Make this series visible
  visible: true,

  // Don't add shadows'
  shadow: false,

  // Set the color of the bars associated to these values
  color: getColor()
});
}
```

Code after resetting zoom:

```
chart.axes[0].setExtremes(chart.axes[0].dataMin, chart.axes[0].dataMax);
var yAxes = chart.yAxis;
var negativeVals = false;

// Check if any of the yAxes contain negative values in the associated dataset
for (var axis in yAxes){
    var minVal = yAxes[axis].dataMin;
    if (minVal < 0){
        negativeVals = true;
    }
}

// Loop through the y-axes
for (var axis in yAxes){

    // Get the min and max vals of the associated dataset
    var minVal = yAxes[axis].dataMin;
    var maxVal = yAxes[axis].dataMax;

    // If we have any negative values
    if (negativeVals){

        // Boolean to determine if the maximum value is larger than the minimum
        var maxGreaterThanMin = maxVal >= (minVal * -1);

        // If the maximum value is greater than the absolute minimum value
        if (maxGreaterThanMin){

            // Calculate min and max
            var maximum = maxVal;
            var minimum = maxVal * -1;

            // Set the extremes of the yAxis
            yAxes[axis].setExtremes(minimum, maximum, false);
        }

        // If the absolute minval is greater than the max value
        else{

            // Calculate the min and max
            var maximum = minVal * -1;
            var minimum = minVal;

            // Set the extremes of the yAxis
            yAxes[axis].setExtremes(minimum, maximum, false);
        }
    }

    // If there are no negative values present at all, we can set the range from 0 to maxVal
    else{
        yAxes[axis].setExtremes(0, maxVal, false);
    }

}

chart.xAxis[0].isDirty = true;
chart.redraw();
```

Edit: solved the problem by overriding the default behaviour when zooming in. I used the min and max values of the selection event to set the extremes of the x-axis. After that I aligned the zero values of the y-axes with an edited version of the code that's called after resetting the zoom. Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5m9JW/355/

Hopefully this can also help people out that run into the same problem.

Comment: Why not use Google Charts ? https://developers.google.com/chart/

Comment: I hadn't looked at Google Charts before. The application I'm implementing is based off a project that was created before that did not work as intended. The project used highcharts and that seemed to work fine. However, Google Charts looks pretty interesting and it seems less complex than Highcharts. I'll look into it when I have the time for it. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Can't edit my previous comment: For security reasons we need to be able to store the js-libraries on our server, which I doubt we can do with Google Charts. If we have to load the libraries through the Google API and if it's possible that data is sent to Google, it's a no go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem by overriding the default behaviour when zooming in. I used the min and max values of the selection event to set the extremes of the x-axis. After that I aligned the zero values of the y-axes with an edited version of the code that's called after resetting the zoom. Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5m9JW/355/ This example works for multiple axes

```
See JS fiddle for my solution
```

Hopefully this can also help people out that run into the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Highcharts doesn't provide options to align yAxis together in the same value (like 0-value for your case). I have a while ago prepared example to make the same position for two axis: http://jsfiddle.net/5m9JW/349/ You probably should be able to upgrade to get the same for more axis

```
while (chart.yAxis[1].translate(0) != chart.yAxis[0].translate(0) && i > 0) {
    chart.yAxis[0].setExtremes(chart.yAxis[0].getExtremes().min - chart.yAxis[0].translate(chart.yAxis[1].translate(0), true));
    i--;
};
```

Also, I think `toPixels()` and `toValue()` would be easier to use than `translate()`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I already got this working when loading in new data. However, I'm looking for a way to zoom in and call my code to align the zeros of the y-axes afterwards if both negative and positive values are present on the y-axis.

I updated your fiddle and added in the zoomType:'xy' setting. After you make the similar zeros, try zooming in on an area that contains values above zero aswell as values below zero. That will display my problem.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5m9JW/351/